# Convert an original binary tree to have it's decorates as the preorder indexes

Tags: java, recursion, tree, traversal

I've had a go, and it works for the left subtree but not the right.

I'm close but my logic is wrong, can anyone help correct and explain the logic to this.

```
public static MyNode preOrderNumbering(MyNode n) {
            if (n != null) {
                n.obj = 0; // Set root decoration to 0;
                preOrderHelper(n, 1); // Set decorations according to preorder.
            }
            return n;
        }

        public static MyNode preOrderHelper(MyNode n, int counter) {
            if (n != null) {
                if (n.left != null) {
                    n.left.obj = counter++; // Set the left object decoration to current count + 1;
                    preOrderHelper(n.left, counter);
                }
                if (n.right != null) {
                    n.right.obj = counter++; // Set the left object decoration to current count + 1;
                    preOrderHelper(n.right, counter);
                }
            }
            return n;
        }
```

Before: [image: http://puu.sh/2k2H7.png]

After:
[image]

Comment: What would be the correct result? The one given as "After:", or something else?

Comment: Yes it should return the tree I labelled "After:".

Comment: As you can see, each node we visit, the decoration increases by one, it's almost like a visual representation of how preorder would be for this tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `counter` with everything that's discovered on the `left` before going to the `right`.

Something like this:

```
public static int preOrderNumbering(MyNode n, int count){
    if(n != null){
        n.obj = ++count;

        count = preOrderNumbering(n.left, count);
        count = preOrderNumbering(n.right, count);

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense! But how can I incorporate this into actually changing the tree?

Comment: I don't know your `MyNode` class, but given this line on your code: `n.obj = 0;` I'm assuming that `obj` is the `int` that represents the value of your node. If that is the case, this line: `n.obj = ++count;` on the example should do the trick. Just invoke the method like: `preOrderNumbering(root,-1)`

Comment: Oh, right yes, thanks for this Francisco, it's clear to me now!

Comment: I prefer 0 as the input, so I believe I can just post increment instead, like so: counter++;

Comment: Glad to have been of help. The post increment is a nice touch ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `counter` by value, not by reference (because that's how Java works), so when the recursion unwinds, so will the counter.

You could update the counter by returning the current value from the recursive call.

Comment: Damn, how can I get around this? I suppose I will have to change quite a bit?